# how to share global variables across threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to end a loop running in a separate thread using a global variable. but this code does not seem to stop the thread in loop. I expect the program not to print any more '.' after 2 seconds, but it still runs indefinitely.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

```
import time
import threading
run = True

def foo():
    while run:
        print '.',

t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
t1.run()
time.sleep(2)
run = False
print 'run=False'
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are executing `foo()` on the main thread by calling `t1.run()`. You should call `t1.start()` instead.
2. You have two definitions of `foo()` - doesn't matter, but shouldn't be there.
3. You didn't put a `sleep()` inside the thread loop (in foo()). This is very bad, since it hogs the processor. You should at least put `time.sleep(0)` (release time slice to other threads) if not make it sleep a little longer.

Here's a working example:

```
import time
import threading
run = True

def foo():
    while run:
        print '.',
        time.sleep(0)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
t1.start()
time.sleep(2)
run = False
print 'run=False'
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: I think they're trying to represent a case where the thread is doing nonstop processing, so point 3 is moot. or are you saying that the lack of even a `time.sleep(0)` prevents other threads from running due to the Global Interpreter Lock?

Comment: @Mike: I'm not so sure about that, but yes, it crossed my mind. That being said, I know newer implementations of Python have fixed some of the GIL's shortcomings, and my version of Python runs this code perfectly well, and it shouldn't prevent other threads from running.

Comment: are the variables syncronized in Python? How can you write and read the same variable at the same time? Don't you need to make a lock?

Answer (score 4):

You don't start a thread by calling `run()`, you start it by calling `start()`.
Fixing that made it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given ...

The variable 'run' is a global variable.

When you modify it within another function, e.g. within the main() function, you must make reference to the variable being global otherwise it will not be globally modified.

```
def main():
    global run
    ...
    run = False
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```